# How do I get a command sent to a process without closing the process?

Tags: perl

I am trying to start up a Postgres client and keep it around so I can send several SQL commands to it and gather the result for each command.  My current problem is the first set of commands don't seem to be sent to the process unless I close the file handle for sending the command.  But closing the file handle defeats the whole purpose of the program.

Here is the code:

```
my ($child_read, $child_write);
our $pid = open2($child_read, $child_write, '../psql -p 2070 super');
print STDOUT $pid . "\n";
$child_write->autoflush(1);

my $output1;
my $theCommands = "set schema 'super'; \n select count(*) from MyTable;";
print $child_write $theCommands;
close($child_write);

print "About to try and get query results. \n";
while (<$child_read>)
{
    print "$_";
}
```

The above code works.  I get the results of the query, but the only way I can get the SQL commands to execute is to close the $child_write file handle.  If I don't close it then the program hangs when trying to read the lines.

How do I get the SQL commands sent to the Postgres client without closing the $child_write file handle?

This is a follow on question to [Looking for help to send queries to Postgres from Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849554/looking-for-help-to-send-queries-to-postgres-from-perl).

Comment: Can you use a postgres driver instead of messing with processes and pipes? http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-2.19.3/Pg.pm

Comment: More: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/retrieve-data-from-a-postgresql-database-using-the-perl-dbi/6039937

Comment: Now that the link is fixed, I see that DBI and DBD::Pg was already recommended to you. For this use case, I would really recommend it. If you still choose to use IPC, a nonblocking read would be more helpful to you. Perhaps you can use IO::Select. Read this discussion thread for more info: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t887094-nonblocking-pipe-open.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Nonblocking Pipe Open thread.  It helped.

Answer (score 2):

You made sure you flushed your output, but you didn't make sure `psql` did the same. You might be able to trick it into flush by using a pseudo tty. [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect) is probably the way to go if you want to continue automatic `psql`.

The simpler and more robust way would be to use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  It makes sense.  I kept reviewing online documentation about open2 and close trying to figure out if there was some way to flush the output.  I hadn't focused on the difference between flushing on my side and flushing on psql's side. I'll check out Expect.